# HCS12 INTERRUPT

Tags: assembly, microcontroller

Shown below is a switch connected to the IRQ or XIRQ pin of the HCS12. Write a program to get the status of the switch and increment a counting sequence on the 7-segment display each time the key is pressed. The switch should be connected to IRQ/PE1 or XIRQ/PE0 of the Trainer (Dragon12P), namely pin 55 (for Maskable Interrupt) or pin 56 (for NonMaskable Interrupt) respectively.

You do not have to get any physical switch; all you need is represent the closure of a switch by grounding the appropriate pin.

Procedure:

1. Initialize and Program the appropriate Interrupt Registers appropriately.
2. Design an appropriate ISR (Interrupt Service Routine).
3. Write down an Assembly code to create a dummy delay loop, and once the key has been pressed, the incremented sequence would appear on the on the 7-segment display and optionally on the LEDs.

Here's my code:

```
#include "C:\Users\CLOS\Desktop\New folder\Reg9s12.H"
TEMP    DC.B 1
RAMEnd  EQU     $1001
MAIN:
        LDS     #RAMEnd+1
        BSET    INTCR,%1100000
        CLR     TEMP
        CLI
        BSET    DDRB,%00010000
        BCLR    PORTB,%00010000
HERE    BRA     HERE
IRQ_EDGE
        LDAA    TEMP
        EORA    #%00010000
        STAA    TEMP
        RTI
        ORG     $FFF2
        DC.W    IRQ_EDGE
        ORG     $FFFE
        DC.W    MAIN
```

The ERROR I'm receiving on Asmide:
Can't Write Target Memory

Comment: Please use Markdown formatting.  Put new lines between your numbered bullets, use four spaces to indicate a code block rather than bold, and use `>` to indicate a quote such as your error message.  Please do not unnecessarily capitalize stuff.  Thanks.  Also, what have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: Try changing `TEMP DC.B 1` to use `RMB` or `DS.B` instead.  But, you also need to place your variable somewhere in RAM and your code somewhere in (EP)ROM.  So, you need appropriate `ORG` directives for your variable section and your code section, similar to how you do for the two vectors at the end.  (And, BTW, your current code does not do anything near your problem description.)